# Use lodash to seperate array into non duplicates and duplicates only

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to do this (with lodash):

from

```
["place of interest", "sightseeing", "monument", "museum", "sightseeing", "museum", "citylife", "monument", "monument"]
```

I want an array without the duplicates

```
["place of interest", "sightseeing", "citylife"]
```

and an array of the duplicates ... but without duplicates of it's own! :)

```
["museum", "monument"]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need lodash to iterate an array? Does the array contain object/arrays, too?

Comment: Doesn't have to be lodash but I'm interested in how you'd do it with lodash. I have a good idea of how'd I'd do it in vanilla js.

I've tried various combinations of _.union, _.difference, _.uniq

No, the arrays will only ever have strings in

Comment: please note in example given 'sightseeing' belongs in the duplicates list not the uniques list

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_.countBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy) and [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs#transform) to create the arrays ([fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/scpmf57x/1/)):

```
var arr = ["place of interest", "sightseeing", "monument", "museum", "sightseeing", "museum", "citylife", "monument", "monument"];

_(arr).countBy(function (item) {
    return item;
}).transform(function (result, n, key) {
    result[n === 1 ? 'unique' : 'duplicates'].push(key);
}, { unique : [], duplicates : [] }).value();
```

And here is a JS only solution ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsu4r674/1/)):

```
var arr = ["place of interest", "sightseeing", "monument", "museum", "sightseeing", "museum", "citylife", "monument", "monument"];

var counts = arr.reduce(function (items, item) {
    items[item] = (items[item] || 0) + 1;
    return items;
}, {});

var results = Object.keys(counts).reduce(function (result, key) {
    result[counts[key] === 1 ? 'unique' : 'duplicates'].push(key);
    return result;
}, {
    unique: [],
    duplicates: []
});

console.log(results);

document.getElementById('results').innerText = JSON.stringify(results);
```

Comment: thanks, impressive, upvoting this as it is a lodash solution

Comment: and you've made me realise i specified the original example incorrectly as 'sightseeing' is not unique - will amend

Comment: I threw myself in the f'ing sea, least I can do